# How to separately control the wifi module in Android development？

Tags: android

Now many Android phones have already support 2*2 mimo which means there are 2 wifi modules inside the phone. I wanna separately control these modules, one for sending signals and the other for receiving signals. How to directly control the hardware? I do not find relevant information in google documents.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no official way / API interface to control the WIFI modules or the antennas directly.

In my opinion, it does not make sense to do so. With MIMO, the best antenna is automatically calculated and used based on the quality of the input signal.

Here is a good explanation from Intel:

> MIMO technology uses a natural radio-wave phenomenon called multipath. With multipath, transmitted information bounces off walls, ceilings, and other objects, reaching the receiving antenna multiple times at different angles and slightly different times. In the past, multipath caused interference and slowed down wireless signals. With multipath, MIMO technology uses multiple, smart transmitters and receivers with an added spatial dimension, increasing performance and range.

https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005714/wireless/legacy-intel-wireless-products.html

What you are planning to do, however, would go against this principle and turn the MIMO antennas into two SISO (Single Input Single Output) antennas.

This would only be possible with a rooted smartphone or an XPOSED module.

If you want to find out how many antennas are built into a smartphone, I would recommend the WIFI Alliance website. Here you can find detailed information about all certified smartphones.

[Website WIFI Alliance](https://www.wi-fi.org/product-finder-results?sort_by=default&sort_order=desc&categories=3)

For Example the Spec Sheet of the Oneplus 6t

[Oneplus 6t WIFI Specs](https://api.cert.wi-fi.org/api/certificate/download/public?variantId=62638)

Comment: really appreciate your answer, my research is to turn a phone into a small radar using wifi modules. Perhaps I have to root the phone to directly control hardware.